# How to determine calculation performance of an FPGA from datasheet?

Tags: fpga, performance

If you have a processor, you can look at the amount of GFLOPS to know something about the FLoating-point Operations Per Second, but how do can you say something about the performance of an FPGA, when you have the datasheet? For example the DE1 SoC FPGA has these specs:

```
Cyclone II 2C20 FPGA
• 18,752 LEs
• 52 M4K RAM blocks
• 240K total RAM bits
• 26 embedded multipliers
• 4 PLLs
• 315 user I/O pins
• FineLine BGA 484-pin package 


 Altera Cyclone® V SE 5CSEMA5F31C6N device
 Altera serial configuration device – EPCQ256
 USB-Blaster II onboard for programming; JTAG Mode
 64MB SDRAM (16-bit data bus)
 4 push-buttons
 10 slide switches
 10 red user LEDs
 Six 7-segment displays
 Four 50MHz clock sources from the clock generator
 24-bit CD-quality audio CODEC with line-in, line-out, and microphone-in jacks
 VGA DAC (8-bit high-speed triple DACs) with VGA-out connector
 TV decoder (NTSC/PAL/SECAM) and TV-in connector
 PS/2 mouse/keyboard connector
 IR receiver and IR emitter
 Two 40-pin expansion header with diode protection
 A/D converter, 4-pin SPI interface with FPGA
```

Source: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse467/15wi/docs/DE1_SoC_User_Manual.pdf 
How can you say something about how fast you can do arithmetic operations, like multiplying, shifting and adding and how many arithmetic operations can be executed in parallel?

Comment: The only useful information in that list is `5CSEMA5F31C6N`. Now you need to look that part up in Altera's databooks and see what's inside it...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Unfortunately, I couldn't find something that is clear about the calculation performance: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/591/cv_51001-230691.pdf

Comment: You won't, directly. You have to know (or work out) what your computation needs in terms of LEs, memories, DSPs, multipliers etc, how fast you can run these, and compare the resources you need with those available in the chip.

Answer (score 1):

A FPGA is very flexible and can be tailored to many use cases. So it depends on the use case which "performance indicator" is the main indicator.

For CPUs, frequency was the main indicator for a long time. But it changed to number of cores, number of memory channels, cache size, instruction set, .... and of cause frequency. The best way to find a suitable CPUs is to use benchmarks, to see if a certain CPU or system fulfills all requirements.

It's the same for FPGAs, they have many performance indicators. How one of them should be weighted depends on the field of application.

FPGAs can be measured in:

- Area:

  - LUTs, LEs, CLB, Gate equivalents
  - Registers, Shifters
  - Multiplier, Adders, DSP blocks
  - Embedded SRAM (e.g. BlockRAM)
- Speed:

  - \$F_{max}\$ of the logic
  - \$F_{max}\$ of I/O pins
  - \$F_{max}\$ of serial transceivers
- Performance:

  - Raw I/O performance: TBit/s
  - DSP operations (e.g. Giga Multiply-Accumulate per second - GMAC/s)
- Hard Macros:

  - Embedded DRAM controllers
  - Embedded CPUs (PowerPC, ARM, ...)
  - Embedded Ethernet, Interlaken or PCI Express IP cores
- ...

So for example, if you want to design a big DSP algorithm, the DSP performance is a good starting point.

Comment: So, what do you know about the performance, if you have something like:
Cyclone II 2C20 FPGA
• 18,752 LEs
• 52 M4K RAM blocks
• 240K total RAM bits
• 26 embedded multipliers
• 4 PLLs
• 315 user I/O pins
• FineLine BGA 484-pin package

Comment: @Wale What do you want to do with the FPGA? It's the same with CPUs: You say Home Theater PC and I say e.g. Intel Atom; you say compiling the complete GCC suite once per day and I could say for example quad way Intel Xeon system with 48 GB RAM; you say coffee machine controller and I might say 8051 (8 bit CPU). We need some context to answer you question. A Cyclone II is old (newest: Cyclone V) and very small compared to other FPGAs on the market.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian commented, you need to know what your computation needs.

You actually have that problem with a processor too - it may have a theoretical peak number of GFLOPS, but if your particular usage of it doesn't allow the operations to be parallel, or bounces all over the memory so the caches don't work very efficiently, you won't get anywhere close to that maximum.

Now, Cyclone V FPGAs are not suited to floating-point maths - they can do it but you burn a lot of their logic capacity doing so.

So, if:

- you can keep your numbers so they fit the naturally fixed-point (and weird - to software engineers - non-power-of-2 width!) multipliers,
- and use all of the DSP units all the time,
- and have the FPGA-chops to be able to write code that will run them at close to their maximum clock rate,
- and you can get all the data in and out at the appropriate rate,

lets see what you could potentially achieve:

- That device has 300 multipliers in it, and 150 pre-adders and accumulators. Up to 600 ops per cycle
- They might clock at up to 200MHz absolutely flat out (I can't quickly lay my hands on the correct number)

So, if you can use those multipliers and adders to their full potential, you could get 600x200M = 120G operations/sec - just from the DSP blocks.  There's then a barrel-load of logic you can put your control functions into, or use for yet more arithmetic.

The great thing about FPGAs (and a big problem too) is their flexibility - there are so many options, even within one device!